# I am running into an Index out of Range Error in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift programming and I am running into an error on the bolded piece of code below, this is my first post ever on Stack Overflow and am trying to figure out how to fix this Index out of Range Error. Any help would be greatly awesome!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet weak var trueButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var falseButton: UIButton!

    let quiz = [

    ["Four + Two is equal to Six.", "True"],
    ["Five - Three is greater than One", "True"],
    ["Three + Eight is less than Ten, False"]

    ]

    var questionNumber = 0



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        updateUI()


    }

    @IBAction func answeredButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {


        let userAnswer = sender.currentTitle // True, False
        **let actualAnswer = quiz[questionNumber][1]**

        if userAnswer == actualAnswer {
            print("Right!")
        } else {
            print("Wrong")
        }

        if questionNumber  + 1 < quiz.count {
            questionNumber += 1

        } else {
            questionNumber = 0
        }


        updateUI()

    }

    func updateUI() {

        questionLabel.text = quiz[questionNumber][0]
    }

}
```

Comment: Remove `[1]`.Why is it there?

Comment: @Rob because the answer is the second element of the inner arrays

Comment: `["Three + Eight is less than Ten, False"]` seems wrong to me

Comment: As @MadProgrammer pointed out the last element of the array only has one item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow! The reason you get the crash error index out of range when you attempt to extract the boolean string is because the element of your **index 2** has a single string.

```
["Three + Eight is less than Ten, False"]
```

Simply put the `"` in there.

```
["Three + Eight is less than Ten", "False"]
```

One more approach you can consider is to use `Tuple` or `Dictionary`.

If you use `Tuple`, and you commit the same mistake, it will give you a compile-time error, like:

> Heterogeneous collection literal could only be inferred to '[Any]';
>   add explicit type annotation if this is intentional

**Tuple example:**

```
let quiz = [

    ("Four + Two is equal to Six.", "True"),
    ("Five - Three is greater than One", "True"),
    ("Three + Eight is less than Ten", "False")

]

let answer = quiz[2].1
```

---

As suggested by Paulw, a better way would be making a model. Like:

**Quiz.swift**

```
struct Quiz {
    /// Contains the question string.
    var question: String
    /// Consider changing this to `Bool`.
    var answer: String
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let quiz = [
    Quiz(question: "Four + Two is equal to Six.", answer: "True"),
    Quiz(question: "Five - Three is greater than One", answer: "True"),
    Quiz(question: "Three + Eight is less than Ten", answer: "False")
]

let answer = quiz[2].answer
```

Comment: Holy Crap, you are awesome! Have to learn to back even further I was so stuck on that line of the code and the "if" statement that I totally didn't look far back. I greatly appreciate your help on this.

Comment: @Glenn A `Question` struct would probably be nicer

Comment: @Paulw11my next lesson that I am taking is going over Structs right now!

Comment: Agreed. Make a model, I added a quick example, as suggested by Paulw. @Esore